# Syntax Error with lists in python / pygame

Tags: list, python-2.7, pygame

I have a game I'm writing which uses pygame and python. I lists to spawn enemies and the lists are really long. The problem code is this:

```
suitors_enemies = [suitor1_1, suitor1_2, suitor1_3, suitor1_4, suitor1_5, suitor1_6, suitor1_7 suitor1_8, suitor1_9, suitor1_10, suitor1_11, suitor1_12, suitor1_13, suitor1_14, suitor1_15, suitor1_16, suitor1_17, suitor1_18, suitor1_19, suitor1_20, suitor1_21, suitor1_22, suitor1_23, suitor1_24,
            suitor2_1, suitor2_2, suitor2_3, suitor2_4, suitor2_5, suitor2_6, suitor2_7 suitor2_8, suitor2_9, suitor2_10, suitor2_11, suitor2_12, suitor2_13, suitor2_14, suitor2_15, suitor2_16, suitor2_17, suitor2_18, suitor2_19, suitor2_20, suitor2_21, suitor2_22, suitor2_23, suitor2_24,
            suitor3_1, suitor3_2, suitor3_3, suitor3_4, suitor3_5, suitor3_6, suitor3_7 suitor3_8, suitor3_9, suitor3_10, suitor3_11, suitor3_12, suitor3_13, suitor3_14, suitor3_15, suitor3_16, suitor3_17, suitor3_18, suitor3_19, suitor3_20, suitor3_21, suitor3_22, suitor3_23, suitor3_24,
            suitor4_1, suitor4_2, suitor4_3, suitor4_4, suitor4_5, suitor4_6, suitor4_7 suitor4_8, suitor4_9, suitor4_10, suitor4_11, suitor4_12, suitor4_13, suitor4_14, suitor4_15, suitor4_16, suitor4_17, suitor4_18, suitor4_19, suitor4_20, suitor4_21, suitor4_22, suitor4_23, suitor4_24,
            suitor5_1, suitor5_2, suitor5_3, suitor5_4, suitor5_5, suitor5_6, suitor5_7 suitor5_8, suitor5_9, suitor5_10, suitor5_11, suitor5_12, suitor5_13, suitor5_14, suitor5_15, suitor5_16, suitor5_17, suitor5_18, suitor5_19, suitor5_20, suitor5_21, suitor5_22, suitor5_23, suitor5_24]
suitors_wave1 = [suitor1_1, suitor1_2, suitor1_3, suitor2_1, suitor2_2, suitor2_3, suitor3_1, suitor3_2, suitor3_3, suitor4_1, suitor4_2, suitor4_3, suitor5_1, suitor5_2, suitor5_3]
suitors_wave2 = [suitor1_4, suitor1_5, suitor1_6, suitor1_7 suitor1_8, suitor1_9, suitor2_4, suitor2_5, suitor2_6, suitor2_7 suitor2_8, suitor2_9, suitor3_4, suitor3_5, suitor3_6, suitor3_7 suitor3_8, suitor3_9, suitor4_4, suitor4_5, suitor4_6, suitor4_7 suitor4_8, suitor4_9, suitor5_4, suitor5_5, suitor5_6, suitor5_7 suitor5_8, suitor5_9]
suitors_wave3 = [suitor1_10, suitor1_11, suitor1_12, suitor1_13, suitor1_14, suitor1_15, suitor1_16, suitor1_17, suitor1_18, suitor2_10, suitor2_11, suitor2_12, suitor2_13, suitor2_14, suitor2_15, suitor2_16, suitor2_17, suitor2_18,]
suitors_boss = [king_suitor]
```

Then i get a syntax error like this:

```
  File "the_odyssey.py", line 1718
    suitors_enemies = [suitor1_1, suitor1_2, suitor1_3, suitor1_4, suitor1_5, su
itor1_6, suitor1_7 suitor1_8, suitor1_9, suitor1_10, suitor1_11, suitor1_12, sui
tor1_13, suitor1_14, suitor1_15, suitor1_16, suitor1_17, suitor1_18, suitor1_19,
suitor1_20, suitor1_21, suitor1_22, suitor1_23, suitor1_24,

                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea what it is, I haven't seen anything like it. I have python 2.7.5 and run mac os 10.9.1. That "syntax error" is the first line of an array. I have tried putting the whole array into one line but it doesn't change the syntax error.

Comment: You've forgotten a `,` between all `suitorX_7`s and `suitorX_8`s

Comment: wow. thanks :D i feel really silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between all your suitor_x_7 and suitor_x_8, you forgot to place a comma.